# Regex to pull img src attribute from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

What regexp do I need in javascript to extract part of an img src when it can be either a jpg or png? My end result should be "/img.happykitten.png" or "/img.happykitten.jpg"

The original string is in the form of "assets/img/happykitten.png"

I tried this but it's not working:

```
  var productImg = $('.image-holder').html(),
      regex = /\/img.*(png|jpg)/,
      productImgSrc = regex.exec(productImg)[0];
```

Comment: What have you tried? What ain't working?

Comment: An example of the string and the desired result of that string is hhighly appreciated!

Comment: The string is the img src in the form /assets/img/image1.png. The desired result is everything after and including /img, regardless of whether it's a png or jpg

Comment: Use the non-gready mode `/\/img.*?(?:png|jpg)/` (notice `?` after `.*`) and the group `(png|jpg)` non-capturing like this `(?:png|jpg)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XrbVGy/3)

Regex:

```
/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg)/gm
```

Everything from the beginning of the file until the extension is matched `\/.*?`

Only files ending in **.png** or **.jpg** are taken into account `\.(?:png|jpg)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal implementation in JavaScript...

```js
(function () {
  var regex = /\.(jpg|png)$/,
      images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
      arr = [];
      
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(images[i].src)) {
      arr = images[i].src.split('/');
      console.log('/img.' + arr[arr.length - 1]);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="assets/img/happykitten.jpg">
  <img src="assets/img/happykitten.gif">
  <img src="assets/img/happykitten.svg">
  <img src="assets/img/happykitten.png">
 </body>
</html>
```